# const formattedStartDate = format(new Date(startDate), "dd MMMM yy"); No overload matches this call

Tags: typescript

[image]

hello , i was deploying my project and it's stumble on this error

[image]

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(value: string | number | Date): Date', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | string[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Date'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | Date'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(value: string | number): Date', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | string[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.ts(2769)
```

Comment: Please don't share images of your code. Copy the code into the post itself instead.

Answer (score 0):

the query parameters can be string, string[] or undefined ... to make this work, you'll have to do something like `new Date(startDate as string)`

```
const formattedEndDate = format(new Date(endDate as string), "dd MMMM yy")
```